# Using MySQL to run the same query on Mulitple Databases

Tags: mysql

We have 100+ databases with identical schemas on the same server.  I need to run the identical select statement on all databases and return the results.  I have looked thru several posts about altering many dbs and have tried this:

```
SELECT CONCAT
    ('SELECT * FROM ', a.table_schema,  '.tableIwant
    GROUP BY CONCAT(emp_id, "-", other_id)
    HAVING count(CONCAT(emp_id, "-", other_id)) >1')
FROM information_schema.tables a 
WHERE a.table_schema LIKE 'table_prefix_%'
GROUP BY a.table_schema;
```

But all this returns is a list of queries.
I know that I could do this using PHP - build an list of all the dbs with one query, then a WHILE loop over the result set, etc.  But I want to do this from MySQL, is there a way?

UPDATE:

Thanks to @KayakJim I have tried to create a Stored Procedure to solve this:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE checkDuplicates()
BEGIN

DECLARE bDone INT;
DECLARE dbname VARCHAR(20);
DECLARE count1, count2 INT;
DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR SELECT table_schema FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_schema like 'table_%' GROUP BY table_schema;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET bDone = 1;


CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS db1.tblResults  (
name VARCHAR(20),
countDupes INT,
countDupesAll INT
) ENGINE = MEMORY
;

OPEN curs;

SET bDone = 0;

REPEAT
FETCH curs INTO dbname;

SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM dbname.table
GROUP BY CONCAT(emp_id, "-", other_id) 
HAVING count(CONCAT(emp_id, "-", other_id)) >1;

SET count1 =  FOUND_ROWS();

SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM dbname.table
GROUP BY CONCAT(emp_id, "-", other_id, "-", param) 
HAVING count(CONCAT(emp_id, "-", other_id, "-", param)) >1;

SET count2 = FOUND_ROWS();

UNTIL bDone END REPEAT;

  CLOSE curs;
  SELECT * FROM db1.tblResults;
END;
//

CALL checkDuplicates();
```

The problem now is that when I execute, it returns an error 1049: Unknown database 'information_schema'.  When I take that query and run it alone I get no errors, and it returns a list of databases that match the WHERE clause.

Comment: What happens if you change it to `information_schema` (i.e. lowercase and enclosed in backticks)?

Answer (score 0):

The solution you posted using PHP could be done inside a Stored Procedure, which would keep the logic inside MySQL as you are desiring.

Comment: Thanks, let's assume for fun that I need a little more help with a Stored Procedures, I would define the SP, using the first query as a variable, then the 2nd query uses the variable for db_name.  Then CALL the SP?